# How to add a view dynamically inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-recyclerview

I was making a `RecyclerView inside a fragment`. I created  objects of my RecyclerView Adapter and LinearLayoutManager through the Java code.

```
public class RFPMenuFragment extends Fragment{

    List<MyRFP> myRFPList;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewRFP;
    RVAdapterRFP rvAdapterRFP;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_feed, container, false);

        recyclerViewRFP = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_rfp);

        initializeData();


        rvAdapterRFP = new RVAdapterRFP(myRFPList);
        recyclerViewRFP.setAdapter(rvAdapterRFP);

        llm  = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewRFP.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return view;
}
```

But its giving me a `NullPointerException` on the line having the setAdapter method. Even when I remove the 2 Adapter lines, I get this error on the setLayoutManager method. How do I fix this?

Here's my LogCat:

```
                                                                       Process: com.example.h8pathak.jobs, PID: 26848
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.h8pathak.jobs.rfp.RFPMenuFragment.onCreateView(RFPMenuFragment.java:41)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add your `single_feed.xml` file

Comment: pass context in RVAdapterRFP

Comment: try setting layout manager before setting adapter.

Comment: @jankigadhiya I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: add your `single_feed.xml` file @TheHardRock

Comment: @AlexiosKarapetsas Just look at the link that you've provided yourself and then read my question's `description`. Do you still think that there's similarity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you haven't added the RecyclerView in your single_feed layout.

If this is true, add the following part in the layout you want the RecyclerView to populate the data.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in your case, mention the layout in your `RFPMenuFragment.java` that'll have the RecyclerView not the single_feed layout (if it does, what its name suggests).

Answer (score 0):

1. As Drup Desai suggested, try setting the layout manager before you set the adapter.
2. Check if the method `initializeData()` is actually initializing and populating your data list. A `null` list might be causing the NPE when the adapter is attached to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Shifting the setLayoutManager method does not help. And I have checked, the data list is being populated.

Answer (score -1):

In `onCreateView`, the fragment is not yet attached to the activity, hence `getActivity()` returns null. You need to instantiate your layout manager, adapter and recyclerview in `onActivityCreated()`

Edit: Code

```
public class RFPMenuFragment extends Fragment{

List<MyRFP> myRFPList;
RecyclerView recyclerViewRFP;
RVAdapterRFP rvAdapterRFP;
LinearLayoutManager llm;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_feed, container, false);
    recyclerViewRFP = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_rfp);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initializeData();

    rvAdapterRFP = new RVAdapterRFP(myRFPList);
    recyclerViewRFP.setAdapter(rvAdapterRFP);

    llm  = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewRFP.setLayoutManager(llm);
}
```

Comment: The findViewById() method is not working in onActivityCreated().

Comment: You can instantiate the views in `onCreateView`, but do everything else in `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Now its giving the NullPointerException in the onActivityCreated method.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace please?

Comment: This is wrong, `onCreateView()` is called after `onAttach()`, so the fragment is attached to its context when `onCreateView()` is called.